# Unable To Send Email From DataBricks Notebook

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-python-sdk

I am trying to write Notebook on Azure Databrick for sending email but it is not sending any email

```
import smtplib
from pathlib import Path
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate
from email import encoders


def send_mail(send_from = "mohit@comapany.com", send_to ="mohitgupta@gmail.com", subject = "Test", message = "Test", files=["/dbfs/FileStore/MOhit_test/Sample_Spreadsheet_10_rows_1.csv"],
              server="smtp-mail.outlook.com", port=587, username='mohit@comapany.com', password='Mypassword',
              use_tls=True):

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = send_from
    msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach(MIMEText(message))

    for path in files:
        part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
        with open(path, 'rb') as file:
            part.set_payload(file.read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition',
                        'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(Path(path).name))
        msg.attach(part)

    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(server, port)
    if use_tls:
        smtp.starttls()
    smtp.login(username, password)
    smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())
    smtp.quit()
```

I tried multiple times to run but its not working but its getting executed but I am not getting any email. Please suggest me whats the issue in this code

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to send mail from an Azure Databricks notebook with file attachments:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

sender_email = "<senderMailId>"
recipient_email = "<recipientMailId>"
subject = "Mail from Databricks notebook"
message_body = "Hi, I am from Databricks notebook"
smtp_server = "smtp-mail.outlook.com"
smtp_port = 587

dbfs_file_paths = ["/dbfs/<filepath>", "/dbfs/FileStore/<filepath>"] 
smtp = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, smtp_port)
smtp.starttls()
smtp.login("<senderMailId>", "<password>")

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = sender_email
msg['To'] = recipient_email
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg.attach(MIMEText(message_body, 'plain'))

for dbfs_file_path in dbfs_file_paths:
    with open(dbfs_file_path, "rb") as attachment:
        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload(attachment.read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', f'attachment; filename="{dbfs_file_path.split("/")[-1]}"')
        msg.attach(part)

smtp.sendmail(sender_email, recipient_email, msg.as_string())
smtp.quit()
```

The code will run successfully, as shown below:

[image]

The mail will be sent to the recipient successfully, as shown below:

[image]